# EXC_BAD_ACCESS with Timer.scheduledTimer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, uiimageview

I'm making an app that involves changing UIImageViews by each second/step from a 4-step countdown timer. I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when my program tries to execute the timer:

```
func startTimer(slider_Value: Float, coin: Int){
    let delay = Double(slider_Value/5)
    var i = 1
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: true){(timer) in
        if i>4{
            timer.invalidate()
        }else{
            switch(i){
            case 1:
                self.lowerTimer.image = UIImage(named: "P1Timer1")
                self.upperTimer.image = UIImage(named: "P2Timer1")
                i = i+1
            case 2:
                self.lowerTimer.image = UIImage(named: "P1Timer2")
                self.upperTimer.image = UIImage(named: "P2Timer2")
                i = i+1
            case 3:
                self.lowerTimer.image = UIImage(named: "Timer3")
                self.upperTimer.image = UIImage(named: "Timer3")
                i = i+1
            case 4:
                self.logo.image = UIImage(named: "Timer4_Logo")
                i = i+1
            default:
                self.lowerTimer.image = UIImage(named: "Timer0")
                self.upperTimer.image = UIImage(named: "Timer0")
                self.logo.image = UIImage(named: "SwipeIsh_Logo")
                i = i+1
            }
        }
    }
```

Not really sure why this crash happens when I run the app. Where XCode tells me the app crashes is when the timer is executed (I also set up a "var timer: Timer?" way earlier in the program). Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Have you set a breakpoint in your timer closure and stepped through to see what is happening?

Comment: @Paulw11 It is occurring at the third line from inside the function ("timer = Timer.scheduledTimer...") It says the crash is occurring within Thread 1, which I am not sure what that means?

Comment: If you add a breakpoint to the line `if I>4 {`, does it stop at that line?  Can you then step through the code?  Have you connected the image view outlets to the storyboard?